# Error reading audio with python on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyaudio

When running the following code using python 2.7 (in Ubuntu 14.04)

```
import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
```

I get the following exception:

> ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:618:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
>
> bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>
> bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>
> bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>
> bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Connection refused (111)
>
> ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1022:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>
> Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
>
> Cannot connect to server request channel jack server is not running or cannot be started

Your help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Same error in ubuntu 20.04 python3.6

Answer (score 2):

Do you have `bluez-alsa` package installed? If so remove it, and re-test. Should get rid of the errors.

If not there is also some discussion here (https://github.com/Katee/quietnet/issues/18) that might be helpful.

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:7843:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

The underun is likely caused because pulseaudio is already accessing 
the card - you can pause it using http://linux.die.net/man/1
/pasuspender. In general to avoid such deadlock, you need a 
soundserver like jackd https://help.ubuntu.com/community/What%20is%20JACK, but you already figured this out from the following log
entries in your trace ;-) (apt-get install jackd)
```

Comment: I removed  bluez-alsa and the "bt_audio_service_open" errors were removed, but the recording still does not work